# How to delete a QGraphicsItem which have some child items as member?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a custom item which inherits QGraphicsItem. It has some child graphics items as member variables. In which order should I remove these items from the scene and how to delete them?

Comment: Note that adding them as members doesn't mean they are *children* in the sense Qt defines this relation. You have to set a *parent* in the going-to-be-children items, namely yourself (`this`), either in the constructor or afterwards with `childItem->setParent(this)`.

Comment: They are member variables and takes the main item as a parent.

Comment: Then everything is fine. But this comment might be of importance for future readers, as it might be a mistake one can do easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create your member graphics items like this:

```
class MyClass : public QGraphicsItem
{
    ...
private:
    
    SomeKindOfGraphicsItem* _item1;
    SomeOtherGraphicsItem* _item2;
}
```

---

```
MyClass::MyClass( ... ) :
    QGraphicsItem( ... ),
    _item1( new SomeKindOfGraphicsItem( ..., this ) ),
    _item2( new SomeOtherGraphicsItem( ..., this ) )
{
    ...
}
```

In that case, it is sufficient to remove only the parent item (`MyClass` in this example) from the scene. This will remove all child items as well:

> **void QGraphicsScene::removeItem(QGraphicsItem * item)**
>
> Removes the item item and all its children from the scene. The ownership of item is passed on to the caller (i.e., QGraphicsScene will no longer delete item when destroyed).

Also, when an object of `MyClass` gets deleted, it will delete all of its children through `Qt` mechanics:

> **QGraphicsItem::~QGraphicsItem() [virtual]**
>
> Destroys the QGraphicsItem and all its children. If this item is currently associated with a scene, the item will be removed from the scene before it is deleted.
>
> Note: It is more efficient to remove the item from the QGraphicsScene before destroying the item.

Comment: Do I need to delete child items in destructor? That might have caused the problem in fact.

Comment: @fatma.ekici No, this happens automatically. Indeed, if you do it manually, you have a *double delete*, which will crash your program! The same is for widget types and other QObject types, by the way. They all form a *tree*; if you delete a node from the tree, all children will be deleted *recursively*; this process is automatically done by Qt. You just have to care that they *are* in a tree, which happens by passing the parent on their constructor (the `this` in the member initializer list in the code of this answer is the key).

Comment: I do not delete any of the child items in main item's destructor. But when I call delete mainItem after removing it from scene, the program crashes.

Comment: If I do not call delete mainItem and only remove the item from scene, some parts of the item still remain on the scene

Comment: Thanks @leemes. I solved the problem. It turns out that I have created a child member in paint function accidentally. In short, there is no need to call removeItem for child items and no need to delete child items in parent item's destructor.

Comment: Thanks for this post so the simpliest way is too delete the object directly. In my project if I call removeItem before delete it, it causes some memory leak, don't know why. (It seems after removeItem the code DO search into the childItem of removed)